# Excel - convert newline (alt+enter) single cell content to different rows

Tags: excel

[image: img]I have some content in an excel cell in the form of numbers separated by alt + enter (newline), how could I transfer all content to different rows?[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfnYV.png)
(actually first image should be the second)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can follow this.

Your text with "alt-Enter"

[image]

Click data then text to columns

[image]

Follow this settings

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: img]
But if we have an additional column like in the picture, how can be the job done?